# "Welcome back!" banner shows unclickable search box

Tags: bug, design

I arrived at a question on *Seasoned Advice* (I assume it applies to all stack exchange sites which is why I posted here) and it showed this banner:

[image]

Two issues:

- The search box is visible.  But you can't give it focus.  So when trying to search, this confused me a for a little while.
- The gray top and white bottom also seems weird.

I guess this is all due to opacity.  Seems like an unhelpful design choice?

Comment: Unhelpful? I can't see the search bar in your image. Only when I hold my finger on a touch screen, it starts to get visible. It's a non-issue to me.

Comment: Interesting.  For me, it's very visible.  Must be due to monitor/screen differences.

Comment: Well, the banner is translucent so that's by design

Comment: @AnthonyPham It's not supposed to be, no.